# gwt super dev mode debugging with Eclipse IDE

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to use Eclipse IDE for debugging Client side code in a GWT application with super dev mode, I've tried SDBG plugin but variable names are not same as they are in Java.

Is there any way that we can enable classic debugging mode in super dev mode?.

Comment: The Answer ist No.
[There are only this Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267067/client-side-gwt-debugging-in-super-dev-mode)