# Client Side GWT Debugging in Super Dev Mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, client, gwt-super-dev-mode

I was debugging a GWT in Eclipse using "Super Dev Mode", Java 8, and Eclipse Photon. I've put breakpoints in the client side of the code, but none of them seem to trigger.

I'm reading the documentation, but it appears to relate to "Legacy Dev Mode" debugging.
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html

Does anyone have any recommendations to "step through" client side code with  "Super Dev Mode"?

Answer (score 2):

If you use GWT's Super Dev Mode, debugging is done completely in the browser and the Super Dev Mode provides sourcemaps to know where in your "Java"-code you currently are. You have to use e.g. Chrome's Developer-Tools and set breakpoints there.

Here is a tutorial how to use the Debugging-Feature of Chrome:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: I can probably use the same technique in Firefox right since that supports source mapping too?

Comment: I recommend to use Chrome for all GWT debugging. FF is veeeeerrrryyyyy slow when project gets big.

Comment: I would but my company doesn't support Chrome and they won't let us download non-standard development tools without business exceptions. That is my problem though. The source map break points do work in firefox though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GWT eclipse plugin by Branflake : https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

Check out his youtube tutorial videos linked from the github page : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU7ZQVLR5Zo&list=PLBbgqtDgdc_TqzA-qXrjgTFMC_6DKAQyT

With this plugin you can debug from within Eclipse with SuperDevMode.

Another option is to use the Ultimate (not free) version of IntelliJ. This has GWT support built in including debugging from within the IDE.